# Summing Rows in Pandas Dataframe returning NAN

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to take the sum of each row in my Pandas Dataframe:

`new_df['cash_change'] = new_df.sum(axis=0)`

However my results keep returning `NaN`

I think it might have something to do with when I convert my **positions** to **Decimal** for multiplication:

`pos_to_dec = np.array([Decimal(d) for d in security.signals['positions'].values])`

Which I have to do to multiply my columns together. I cast it back however:

`cash_change[security.symbol] = cash_change[security.symbol].astype(float)`

Here is the complete method. Its objective is to perform some column multiplication for each **security** then **sum** the total at the end:

```
def get_cash_change(self):
    """
    Calculate daily cash to be transacted every day. Cash change depends on
    the position (either buy or sell) multiplied by the adjusted closing price
    of the equity multiplied by the trade amount.
    :return:
    """
    cash_change = pd.DataFrame(index=self.positions.index)
    try:

        for security in self.market_on_close_securities:
            # First convert all the positions from floating-point to decimals
            pos_to_dec = np.array([Decimal(d) for d in security.signals['positions'].values])

            cash_change['positions'] = pos_to_dec
            cash_change['bars'] = security.bars['adj_close_price'].values

            # Perform calculation for cash change
            cash_change[security.symbol] = cash_change['positions'] * cash_change['bars'] * self.trade_amount

            cash_change[security.symbol] = cash_change[security.symbol].astype(float)

            # Clean up for next security
            cash_change.drop('positions', axis=1, inplace=True)
            cash_change.drop('bars', axis=1, inplace=True)

    except InvalidOperation as e :
        print("Invalid input : " + str(e))

    # Sum each equities change in cash
    new_df = cash_change.dropna()

    new_df['cash_change'] = new_df.sum(axis=0)

    return cash_change
```

My `new_df` Dataframe ends up looking something like this:

```
                MTD       ESS      SIG       SNA  cash_change
price_date                                                   
2000-01-04      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-05      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-06      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-07      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-10      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-11      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-12      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-13      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-14      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-18      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-19      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-20      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-21      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-24      0.0   1747.83  1446.71      0.00          NaN
2000-01-25   3419.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
2000-01-26      0.0      0.00     0.00   1660.38          NaN
2000-01-27      0.0      0.00 -1293.27      0.00          NaN
2000-01-28      0.0      0.00     0.00      0.00          NaN
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Or possibly another way to sum the columns for each row?

Comment: I'd suggest to add minimal reproducible example - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. People here are usually willing to help, but I doubt a lot of SO users will play this guessing game with your current question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you supply `axis=0` in the [`DF.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) method, it performs summation along the indexes (vertical direction if it's easier to comprehend). As a result, you get just 4 values computed corresponding to the 4 columns of the dataframe. Then, you are assigning this result to a new column of the dataframe. As they do not share the same index axis to reindex upon, you get a series of `NaN` elements.

You actually want to do the summation across the columns(horizontal direction).

Change that line to:

```
new_df['cash_change'] = new_df.sum(axis=1)  # sum row-wise across each column
```

Now you would get finite computed summed values.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df['cash_change'] = new_df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: This was what OP tried initially which were causing `NaNs` to appear.

Comment: @nickil maveli OP tries axis=0

Comment: And may I know how is this different from the answer I posted? If you have something relevant to add to this, please edit your post.

Comment: you posted the answer while i was typing...by the time i finished you had already posted...it is same as yours.